# How can I disable Table Cache in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I want to disable Table Cache for dynamoDB in **Springboot** project. I found this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/dynamodb-table-cache/

but there is C# code for disabling the cache.
`AWSConfigs.UseSdkCache = false;`

Where can I find the code for Java? I am using below maven versions for spring-data-dynamoDB

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.671</version>
</dependency>
```